# binary to decimal converter without using parseint or arrays

Tags: java, string, parsing

Getting string index out of range but I don't understand why I've went through it about 50 times

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class binary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the first binary number");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num1 = keyboard.next();
        //System.out.println("Enter the second binary number");
        //String num2 = keyboard.next();
        
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = num1.length(); i>0;i--) {
            if(num1.charAt(i) == 1) {
                total += 2*i;
            }
            
        }
        if(num1.charAt(3) == 1) {
            total -= 1;
        }
        System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```

Comment: initialize `i = num1.length() - 1`. String index starts from `0` and ends with `length - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete solution to what you're trying to do, including a set of tests:

```
class binary {

    private static int binaryToInt(String binary) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < binary.length(); i++) {
            total *= 2;
            if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
                total += 1;
        }
        return total;
    }

    private static void test(String binary, int expected) {
        int n = binaryToInt(binary);
        String rightWrong = "right";
        if (n != expected) {
            rightWrong = String.format("WRONG! (should be %d)", expected);
        System.out.printf("%s -> %d is %s\n", binary, n, rightWrong);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("0", 0);
        test("1", 1);
        test("10", 2);
        test("100", 4);
        test("111", 7);
        test("0000111", 7);
        test("1010101010", 682);
        test("1111111111", 1023);

        System.out.println("");

        // test sanity check
        System.out.println("This last test should fail (we are just testing the test method itself here)...");
        test("1010101010", 0);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0 -> 0 is right
1 -> 1 is right
10 -> 2 is right
100 -> 4 is right
111 -> 7 is right
0000111 -> 7 is right
1010101010 -> 682 is right
1111111111 -> 1023 is right

This last test should fail (we are just testing the test method itself here)...
1010101010 -> 682 is WRONG! (should be 0)
```

One significant problem in your code hasn't yet been addressed in the comments or earlier answers.  Note this line vs the one in your code:

```
if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
```

You were testing for the numeric value `1`, which is never going to be `true` because you're getting back a character from `charAt()`, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

While `length()` counts the number of elements, their indexes start at 0. For a string of "1111" the last character would be at index 3, not 4, so `.length()-1`. You would need to either change your for statement to `for(int i = num1.length()-1; i>=0;i--)` (notice also the condition change) or change the charAt statement to `if(num1.charAt(i-1) == '1')`.

Also, based on what you are trying to do, I assume for `total += 2*i` you actually need something like `total += Math.pow(2, i-length())` depending on what you decide to do with `i` first.